# How to add a bookmark button to the main Firefox toolbar?

Tags: firefox

I only need a couple of bookmark buttons (and would prefer small favicon-only buttons without text) and don't want to add a whole long bookmark bar. Is there a way to add a button to the main toolbar itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Custom Buttons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/custom-buttons/) is an add-on that allows you to add buttons that can execute custom code and do lots of other interesting things.

See the [CB forum](http://custombuttons.sourceforge.net/forum/) for sample buttons made by other users (you can even share your custom buttons on websites using the *custombutton* protocol). [This thread](http://custombuttons.sourceforge.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=524) provides the basic template for a link button. You can add it to your browser, then edit the URL, modify the icon etc. as per your needs.

Comment: Seems to be a great extension I need for many purposes. If only they had any reasonable documentation...

Comment: Yeah, but the forum is helpful so at least there's that.

Answer (score 1):

To customize your layout, go to `View -> Toolbars -> Customize`, then drag your bookmark items to the location bar.

To further reduce the bookmark items to buttons, you can simply remove the title of the bookmark (as others have suggested) or use a suitable addon (such as [Roomy Bookmarks Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/roomy-bookmarks-toolbar/))

**If you want your bookmarks in drop-down button on main toolbar**

Disable your bookmarks bar, and a button should automatically appear in the main toolbar.

You can disable your bookmarks bar from `View -> Toolbars -> Bookmarks Bar` or by right clicking in the toolbar area.

If a button doesn't appear, you can go to `Customize` from the same menu and drag it into place.

Comment: I think he wants separate link buttons and not the Bookmarks drop-down menu button.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't quite sure what he meant by "add a button to the main toolbar"

Comment: Edited it to better reflect the question.

Comment: Sounds nice but looks and behaves ugly :-(

Answer (score 1):

Yes, actually there is a way without installing any add-ons. Just drag the website to the bookmarks bar, and then right-click and select "Properties" and delete the name of the website. You'll just be left with the favicon :).